# pagination of results post-processed with afterFind

Tags: cakephp, pagination

v1.3
Does anyone have experience of pagination of results that have been subjected to some processing in afterFind() ?

Although the structure of my returned data is identical, bar the addition of two calculated pseudo fields, all of the pagination data seems to have been lost.

Google searches lead to dead-ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted - I'd stripped out the empty arrays that, it turned out, are used by pagination

Comment: I know it's been a while, but care to elaborate? I'm running into a problem where I get errors using paginate and afterFind together.