# CakePHP afterFind() kills the total paginate count

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am using a containable paginate operation and `afterFind()` for removing empty arrays in my records but that makes a problem in pagination.

This is the `afterFind` function:

```
function afterFind($results, $primary=false) {

        if ($primary == true) {
            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                if (empty($value['Orderstatus'])) { 
                    unset($results[$key]); //removing record if the orderstatus is empty
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }
```

Total of four records in the fetch I removed only one empty array (record),

total records in the database 4
removed records using after find is 1

remaining records 3
paginate limit is 2

It shows two records in my first page but I cannot access the second page or the last record that should be in second page.

Comment: does debug($yourPaginatedData); show correct result count..

Comment: NO, I used debug($this->paginate()); in my controller it shows only two records that is whatever i mentioned in paginate limit that much records only showing. but the expecting three records..  Is this correct method to debug whole paginate result???

Comment: try changing your limit to , say, 10 and see the debug result. What does it show..

Comment: If I comment the afterfind function the pagination working fine.. guess in afterfind method doesn't return total paginate count so its can't get the next pages..

Comment: After i changed the limit to 10 it shows all the three records perfectly...

Comment: Is this the same condition as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319710/pagination-of-results-post-processed-with-afterfind   if yes then that might be the case for you too

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have unset the rows that are needed by pagination. I suggest you make your custom paginate function for the model (overriding the default cakePHP's pagination). See a sample link here: [Forced Paginate Count](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-paginate-a-search-using-the-cakephp-framework:48fc5f77-38d0-41e0-b711-77c64834cda3)

Hope it helps in solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not work the condition on the query so records without an OrderStatus are not returned to begin with?